# Angular Cube slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Estoy intentado hacer un slider en forma de cubo siguiendo los pasos de swiper
[Swiper cube](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/240-effect-coverflow.html)

Seguí los pasos pero parece ser que la parte de background-img:url no funciona. La ruta de la imagen es la correcta ya que al usar la etiqueta img funciona. Pero parece ser que para el cubo funcione necesito usar el background.image:url. ¿En angular la etiqueta es diferente?
Este es mi código.

html

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(../../../assets/img/angular.png)"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

home.component.ts

```
 ngAfterViewInit(){

    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      effect: 'coverflow',
      grabCursor: true,
      centeredSlides: true,
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      coverflowEffect: {
        rotate: 50,
        stretch: 0,
        depth: 100,
        modifier: 1,
        slideShadows: true,
      },
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
      },
    });
  
  }
```

css

```
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

.swiper-slide {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: Probablemente copiaste mal el código, porque `efect: 'coverflow'` debería ser `efect: 'cube'`;

Comment: efect: 'cube' tampoco funciona. Encontré esta información pero lía aun más  https://swiperjs.com/angular/        abajo del todo